# Linkaxes for all subplots in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, axes

I am having difficulty making all of my subplots in a (3,4,i) plots have exactly the same axes, all starting at zero. The code I have so far is below but it returns all subplots with varying x and y scales.

Can anybody help?

```
%% plot 
for i = 1:num_bins;
    h = zeros(ceil(num_bins),1);
    h(i)=subplot(4,3,i); 
    plotmatrix(current_rpm,current_torque)
end
linkaxes(h,'xy');
axis([0 30 0 8]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move the memory allocation outside of the loop:

```
%% plot 
h = zeros(ceil(num_bins),1);
for i = 1:num_bins;
    h(i)=subplot(4,3,i); 
    plotmatrix(current_rpm,current_torque)
end
linkaxes(h,'xy');
axis([0 30 0 8]);
```